# Getting POST or PUT request body prior to serialization (.NET, C#)

Tags: c#, .net

We (our dev team) have a need to inspect an inbound POST or PUT request body prior to serialization.

We don't need to transform or manipulate anything, simply be able to see and possibly record the body for future analysis.

We need to look at the raw request body not the request as it was serialized.

This is a straightforward Web API app running on IIS7. Our controllers are based on the system.Web.Http ApiController class.

I investigated finding this in the Request object, but despite it containing a plethora of information about the headers and the like, it did not seem to contain the raw request body, which is what i am looking for. I did find some prior posts that described getting this through the Request.InputStream, but this does not appear to be available in .Net 4.5.

Thanks for any insights.

-r

PS .Net 4.5

Comment: There are several ways to do HTTP requests in .NET

Comment: What serialization? What HTTP framework are you using?

Comment: Really not clear. Who's we? Who send the request? Where are you running? alone, in WCF, in IIS, in ASP, in MVC?

Comment: "We" is the development team. The request is sent from any HTTP enabled client to our service which is a straightforward Web API service running in IIS using controllers based on a controller class derived off ApiController in the.NET 4.5 system.Web.Http

Comment: I've spent quite a bit of time trying to find options. I would think that I could get this from the Request.Content, but unless I am missing something, I don't have access to the raw request body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking at
    [ControllerContext.Request.ToMessage()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.httprequestmessageextensionmethods.tomessage.aspx)

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a champ!